# XML::LibXML unexpected error accessing attribute values

Tags: xml, perl, hash, attributes, libxml2

I am running through the gentle introduction to [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) at [*Perl XML::LibXML by Example*](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/index.html) and cannot seem to get hash attributes working. For example, what is wrong with the following code?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $version = XML::LibXML::LIBXML_VERSION;
my $dot_version = XML::LibXML::LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION;
my $run_version = XML::LibXML::LIBXML_RUNTIME_VERSION;
print "LibXML version: $version\n";
print "LibXML dotted version: $dot_version\n";
print "LibXML runtime version: $run_version\n";
print "Perl version: $^V\n";

my $xml = q{
<record>
  <entry atr1="a" atr2="b" atr3="c" />
</record>
};

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $xml );
my ($entry) = $dom->documentElement->getChildrenByTagName('entry');

print "\$entry is a: ", ref($entry), "\n";
print "node name: ", $entry->nodeName, "\n";
print "Attribute: ", $entry->getAttribute('atr1'), "\n";    # Line 26
print "Attribute: ", $entry->{'atr1'}, "\n";                # Line 27
```

With the following output:

```
$./hashtest.pl 
LibXML version: 20706
LibXML dotted version: 2.7.6
LibXML runtime version: 20706
Perl version: v5.10.1
$entry is a: XML::LibXML::Element
node name: entry
Attribute: a
Not a HASH reference at ./hashtest.pl line 27.
```

I am expecting lines 26 and 27 to have the same output. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

**Edit: Added more complete version information**

Comment: The script work on my system, but if `$entry->getAttribute('atr1')` works, why do you care about `$entry->{'atr1'}`?

Comment: Would be nice if you included `$XML::LibXML::VERSION` too.

Comment: `XML::LibXML::LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION` is a function that returns the version of the underlying libxml library. It's more useful to show the value of scalar `$XML::LibXML::VERSION`, which is the version of the Perl library. The version currently available is 2.0128, and I have established that your code works fine with 2.0124. But please take note of [ikegami's words below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39378246/622310) that the feature you're trying to use is undocumented and so should be considered to be unavailable. I would be interested to learn how you came to think that it would work at all?

Comment: You must be running a *very* old version of `XML::LibXML`. Although you don't show the version of the module, your output shows that it is based on libxml 2.7.6, released seven years ago in October 2009.

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding. I was unable to access a `$XML::LibXML::VERSION` function but was able to find `XML::LibXML::LIBXML_VERSION` so I assume that is what you meant. However these version numbers don't seem that old. Can you elaborate on which version number I should be looking at?

Answer (score 2):

As the author of the guide that you have been using, I'm sorry that you've encountered this problem and feel that the tone of some of the comments and replies here has been unduly harsh.

The code you posted **does** work on versions of XML::LibXML that support it and **is** covered in the [OVERLOADING section of the XML::LibXML::Element docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Element.pod#OVERLOADING).  This "tied hash" interface is a more 'Perlish' way to access attribute values than calling the `getAttribute()` method. One advantage is that the hash access works inside a double-quoted string whereas an explicit method call will not.

From my reading of the [ChangeLog](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/XML-LibXML), this overloading behaviour was added to the Element class in version 1.91 released on 2012-02-21, although the AttributeHash interface has been available since at least 2009.

I have updated the [tutorial section](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/basics.html#tied-attribute-hash) to mention that this function is not available on older versions of XML::LibXML.  I did originally consider including that warning, but decided against it since the feature has been in XML::LibXML for so long.

As a general rule, if you're using a Perl object, it would be considered very poor practice to assume the object was a hashref and poke around inside it to access hash values.  However that's not what's happening in this case and the hash you're accessing has been provided and documented for exactly that purpose.

If I was going to use a method call to get the value, I'd probably use:

```
$entry->findvalue('./@atr1')
```

since this can easily be adapted to access text or attribute content from nested elements as well.

Comment: "I'd probably use `$entry->findvalue('./@atr1')`". Unless you care about performance. Tied hashes are also incredibly slow. Unfortunately, even `getAttribute` got a Perl wrapper in 1.61 for dubious reasons which made me switch to `_getAttribute` in performance-critical code. This is undocumented and bad practice, of course, but it was the only way to avoid serious performance regressions.

Comment: I like the guide. Good job. :)

Comment: @nwellnhof, Re "*Tied hashes are also incredibly slow*", Mostly because they translate into Perl method calls. As such, they're not nearly as slow when compared against an actual Perl sub/method call. However, in this case, we have the method call to get the tied hash on top of the sub call to the tied method, so it should still be very slow.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to use

```
$entry->{'atr1'}
```

was added to XML::LibXML in version 1.91. It's equivalent to

```
$entry->getAttributeHash()->{$name}
```

You must have an older version of XML::LibXML. You could upgrade XML::LibXML, but you might as well use

```
$entry->getAttribute('atr1')
```